# My program is crashing, I can't find why

Tags: c++, methods, crash

I made a program to implement fraction in c++. I made it because it's a kind of homework from a c++ lesson i'm following at home. The program compile but will crash quickly after it was launch. I search an answer myself and all I found was that it crashes when a new object is being created. Here is the code in fault.

```
//a and b are for the numerators and denominator in the fraction: a/b
ZFraction::ZFraction(int numer, int denom):m_numer(numer), m_denom(denom)//this constructor made it crash
{
    if(m_numer != 0)
    {
        m_numer = m_denom % m_numer;
        m_denom = m_denom/m_numer;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Fraction impossible";
    }
}
```

Why is it crashing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You check the wrong value for zero, it's `m_a` that can't be zero. Zero can be divided by anything, but nothing can be divided by zero.

Comment: @Jägermeister You seem to have it backwards; `m_a` and `m_b` are the class members. `a` and `b` are parameters, which are only used to initialise the members. All is well in this regard.

Comment: You need to review the section on fractions in your childhood maths book. That's not how you simplify a fraction.

Comment: @Angew Uups. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: To second what Joachim said, that is why normally do not use names like `a` and `b`, but more descriptive, such as `numerator` and `denominator` or at least `numer` and `denom`. That might make the error more obvious, or even prevent it.

Comment: So, the error was just in the question and your real code has it correctly? If so, please post a [mcve] so that we can hopefully see what's wrong.

Comment: Will it help if i give the full project?

Comment: No, don't post the full project. You have to do the work to isolate the problem.

Comment: No, you are supposed to post your [MCVE]. The act of creating one should be your first debugging step, long before resorting to asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `m_numer` changes between the divisions. For instance, if you have `denom = 20` and `numer = 10`, the line

```
m_numer = m_denom % m_numer
```

assigns `m_numer = 0`. Then you get division by zero on calculation of `m_denom`. I would suggest doing the calculations with the original values, i.e.

```
ZFraction::ZFraction(int numer, int denom):m_numer(numer), m_denom(denom)
{
    if(numer != 0)
    {
        m_numer = denom % numer;
        m_denom = denom/numer;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Fraction impossible";
    }
}
```

On a side note, consider throwing an exception instead of writing on cout, that way you will not have a constructed object with a bogus value if `numer == 0`.

Also, numerator is the name for top of the fraction and not the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Comment: If it helped you, I would appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted so that others do not have to spend time on a question that appears unsolved.